# How to compute longest anagram using trie?

Tags: python, time-complexity, trie

I am currently working on a project that require me to compute the largest anagram group in an dictionary using trie and the return result must in alphabetical order. The solution should compute the result in O(C) time and space complexity where C represent all characters inside dictionary.

I plan to construct the trie by creating new array of size 26 at each node and index of the array  represent a letter from A - Z, eg array[0] = A, array[1] = B etc. I will also map all letter from A - Z to an unique prime so that I can compute an unique number for anagram group.

During insertion, I insert the pointer of next letter's array and the result of multiplication between current letter's prime number and previous letter's prime number to its corresponding index.

I did not certain if my approach is correct as I feel the space complexity probably did not meet the requirement, any suggestion or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing with your "primes", but normally you just want to sort the letters of each word in your input dictionary.

Comment: @o11c Multiplying the primes corresponding to each letter give each anagram group a unique number that can be computed in O(n), where n is the word length; sorting (using TimSort) is O(nlogn).

Comment: I assume the assignment requires that you use a trie. I'd use a dict at each level, rather than a list.

Comment: Okay, I guess that *could* work, but it's still silly. In any case, you're probably going to run into integer overflow problems for words like `hydroxydesoxycorticosterone`, which requires 92 bits (assuming primes are assigned in order) - and if there's user input, it could be arbitrarily long.

Comment: @o11c Oh, I agree that using the sorted letters is much more sensible, and easier to debug. And probably significantly faster than using the primes. But it's not O(n). We don't need to worry about integer overflow because we're using Python. But we can keep the number size down by assigning them in "etaoinshrdlu..." frequency order.

Comment: Ack, my old calculation was wrong, I was just using indices rather than the primes (so any word with an `a` ended up as 0)! With fixed, We're *way* more bits than that - plenty of words in the 250+ bit range, regardless of order (which saves only ~10%).

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I already get hint from my lecturer. I will counting sort all word to aabb format and then use that to construct anagram trie.